# find matching pattern and print the line with the corresponding value

Tags: awk, command-line, pattern-matching, data-manipulation

I have two files, one has only names and other has related values.

The first file looking like this;

```
file1.txt
MSPC_Peak_1
MSPC_Peak_10
MSPC_Peak_10
MSPC_Peak_100
MSPC_Peak_1000
.
.
.
```

and another file like this (we can think this one as a reference)

```
file2.txt
MSPC_Peak_1 603,277
MSPC_Peak_3 690,776
MSPC_Peak_4 520,384
MSPC_Peak_5 4466,64  
.
MSPC_Peak_10 686,17
.
```

And these does not have same line count.

I want to read the line in the file1 and find the same name in the file2 and add the value next to it.

So , output should look like this;

```
MSPC_Peak_1 603,277
MSPC_Peak_10 686,17
MSPC_Peak_10 686,17
. 
.
```

I tried this code

```
'FNR==NR{ arr[$1]; next }$1 in arr' file1 file2
```

This worked. However, does not print repeated values.

Giving an output like;

```
MSPC_Peak_1 603,277
MSPC_Peak_10 686,17
. 
.
```

I could not find the way to fix it in my research since awk is still complicated for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example your are building a associative array `arr` and any repeated value gets overwritten in the process. You end up with unique indexes within the array. That's why the *MSPC_Peak_10* match is only printed once. To get all values simply build a number-indexed array and access all entries while matching.

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{ arr[NR]=$0 } 
    NR!=FNR{ for(i in arr){ 
      if(arr[i]==$1){ print arr[i],$2 } } }' file1 file2
MSPC_Peak_1 603,277
MSPC_Peak_10 686,17
MSPC_Peak_10 686,17
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for this answer and actually, it was working but now with another data, it is not returning any result. Do you have any idea about the reason? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @juylmin Unfortunately I don’t know what the other data you’re using now looks like, so I can only guess here, but I assume maybe your values from file 1 do not not match with the values from file 2. Keep in mind that they have to match exactly and spaces can lead to non matching scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You can just reverse the file processing and get it done using this command:

```sh
awk 'FNR==NR {map[$1]=$2; next} $1 in map {print $1, map[$1]}' file2 file1

MSPC_Peak_1 603,277
MSPC_Peak_10 686,17
MSPC_Peak_10 686,17
```